# How to import Launchy settings from an old install?

Tags: launchy

I have made a new, clean Windows install, but I'd like to copy over my Launchy settings from the old install. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, the local Launchy data is stored under `%AppData%/Launchy` (you can enter exactly this string into a Windows Explorer address bar). `launchy.ini` is the file containing all of your settings, such as indexed folders and preferred matches for any ambiguous strings (such as if you've forced `box` to be used for VirtualBox instead of Dropbox).

The two icon cache folders and `launchy.db`/`history.db` are probably best left where they are, as Launchy will regenerate these anyway the next time you run it.